# Error while compile Angular 14 Bootstrap 5 for modal popup

Tags: angular, bootstrap5-modal

/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2020/ng-bootstrap.mjs:17281:25-40 - Error: export 'createComponent' (imported as 'createComponent') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Compiler, CompilerFactory, Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ContentChild, ContentChildren, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, DebugElement, DebugEventListener, DebugNode, DefaultIterableDiffer, Directive, ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER, ElementRef, EmbeddedViewRef, EnvironmentInjector, ErrorHandler, EventEmitter, Host, HostBinding, HostListener, INJECTOR, Inject, InjectFlags, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector, Input, IterableDiffers, KeyValueDiffers, LOCALE_ID, MissingTranslationStrategy, ModuleWithComponentFactories, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, NgModule,

Comment: show us some of your code, also is createComponent actually something that the angular/core package exports?

Comment: It was working fine if i remove import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: In your module where your component is defined, or in the app.module file, are you importing either the whole ng bootstrap module with NgbModule or individually as is referenced here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#imports

Comment: I have imported in app.module. The complete NgbModule as below. import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'. Am trying to implement modal popup.

Comment: Hmmm, I would say try following their stackblitz. That said I will say their documentation is genuinely shit since following their exact steps in my own stackblitz did not result in any of what they showed https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fmain.ts. Instead I will direct you to material components for angular and their dialog is pretty much the same concept, but it actually works

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: What exact version of Angular 14 are you using?

Comment: Angular 14.0.5 and bootstrap 5.2.0

Answer (score 3):

The same thing was happening to me, but for some reason when I downgraded bootstrap to version 12.1.2 it somehow worked.

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
```